# Get actual folder icon in Windows 10

Tags: c#, winapi, windows-10, pinvoke

I'm trying to get the system icon for specified folder path. I used the code from https://stackoverflow.com/a/23666202/2770274 and it partially works.

The problem is that when I run the application on Windows 10, I still get Windows 8 like icons:

[image]

Left - icon I get / Right - icon I would like to get

How can I get the actual folder icon for Windows 10 in C# code?

Comment: The code in the accepted answer of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23666076/how-to-get-the-icon-associated-with-a-specific-folder/23666202#23666202) question, works perfect.

Comment: Hmmm, strange - it produces old style icons for me. Did you set anything in application manifest or platform target?

Comment: Platform target on my test project is 4.5.2 - rest all default